# Unsuported Android Plugin version: 3.5.3. After upgrading flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded the flutter to 1.12.13+hotfix.5 and after that I am getting the error **Unsuported Android Plugin version: 3.5.3.**

When I downgrade the gradle build to 3.5.2, 3.5.1, 3.5.0+, it shows below error:

> Finished with error: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\TiwariA\Documents\X-Project\build, but the tool couldn't find it.

Below is the screenshot of flutter doctor result:

[image]

**Getting below warnings in Console**

> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-0.4.0+13\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\packageinfo\PackageInfoPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_info-0.4.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\deviceinfo\DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.3+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-6.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemessaging\FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Note: C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   C:\Users\TiwariA\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
>       setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
>                           ^
>   1 warning
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Finished with error: Unsuported Android Plugin version: 3.5.3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue.

It is weired but it was because if define productFlavors in my `app/build.gradle` and not passing `--flavor` to `flutter run`. (eg. `flutter run --flavor myApp`

After adding it it worked for me...

Comment: checkout my answer below @nicolas-perraut

Comment: I do not have flavor in my project

Comment: In my case it worked in the terminal as I added the flavor parameter but not in the IDE because I forgot to configure the `Run/Debug Configurations`

Comment: it worked when I try to add command `flutter build apk --flavor flavor_name`

Answer (score 1):

This question is not that old, but I have a better solution that the proposed solution. Yes, I believe that the problem the OP is running into is the `productFlavors` problem. However my solution is a bit more automated/future-proof. Android Studio actually provides a way for you to supply the android flavor, as long as you have an updated flutter plugin. Here is how:

1. Open your flutter project.
2. Open the Run menu
3. Select 'Edit Configurations...'
   [image: Shows Run menu with an arrow pointing to Edit Configurations]
4. In the Edit Configurations screen, select the Flutter -> main.dart configuation (or whichever config you want to edit) from the left side panel
5. In the right panel, where you edit the settings, you will see a field called 'Build flavor:'. Type in the name of your flavor and hit 'OK'
   [image: Edit Configurations screen, with an arrow pointing to Build flavors field]

I really hope this helps someone.

Comment: checkout this answer. pretty sure this one will automate your build process more. @ashish-tiwari

Comment: I do not have flavor in my project

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I changed the name of the debug apk which cause this problem.
Delete the following code then **successed**.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            outputFileName = "....apk"
        } else {
            outputFileName = "${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk" //delete this code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not specifying the productFlavour for the build.
If you are using Visual Studio Code open .vscode/launch.json and specify the flavor as follows after dart entry:
"args": [
"--flavor"
"flavor-name"
]
Note: flavor-name is a placeholder, replace with your flavor.

If you are using Android Studio follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196033/11447211

Comment: I do not have flavor in my project

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue, resolved by removing source folder and cloning again. I tried every git clean up commands but none of them worked until completely removing and cloning again.